# How can I check if a user is logged in in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I got this form :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        <input type="submit" class="form_submit_button" name="register_interest" value="Add to favourites"/>

        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I want to check if user is logged in and I did this :

```
 {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

And it hides the button if the user is not logged in.

I want that button to show even if I am not logged in and after the form submit to check if the user is logged in .

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [`IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The check must be performed in your php controller. Additionally, you can also perform a javascript check which prevents submitting the form if user is not logged in.

To check for user login in your controller:

```
 if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER') == false) {
      // show some error message, throw exception etc...
  }
```

Another way to do this:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');
```

To check on the client side (javascript), you could do something like this:

```
{% if not is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}

<script>
  // wrap into document.ready() if needed
  $('#your_submit_button_id').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('You must be logged in to use this function');
  });
</script>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
{% if app.user %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <input type="submit" class="form_submit_button" name="register_interest" value="Add to favourites"/>

    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% else %}
     <input type="button" class="form_submit_button" name="register_interest" value="Add to favourites"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi,I want to show the button register interest even if the user is not logged in.I was Thinking about putting a condition in controller  before submitting the form

Comment: You can show your register_button like this way event if user is not logged in. What you want exactly ?

Comment: If you always want to display a button then you do not need an if statement. The question is what kind of action must be done when de user hits the button when he is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy for Symfony5+ todays. I want to share because this page is first result in google searches.

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED');
```